# Error 1064 Inserting Records MySQL

Tags: mysql

Getting error 1064 while inserting records into table `Place`. None of the `INT`values have decimal points.

Table:

```
CREATE TABLE Place (
Place_ID INT (4) NOT NULL,
Type VARCHAR (4), 
Elevation INT (4),
Population INT (4),                                 
AddressInfo VARCHAR(4),                     
ASCIIName VARCHAR(4) NOT NULL,     
Latitude INT (4) NOT NULL,
Longitude INT (4) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (Place_ID)
);
```

Inserted Data:

```
INSERT INTO place VALUES (‘1000119’, ‘Beijingshan’, ‘0’, ‘1032934’, ‘740 Dragon Dr. 93402’, ‘PPL’, ‘29’, ‘118’);
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'Dragon Dr. 93402', 'PPL', '29', '118')' at line 1
```

Please let me know if I can provide additional information.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using the wrong quotes. Try

```
INSERT INTO place 
VALUES (1000119,'Beijingshan',0,1032934,'740 Dragon Dr. 93402','PPL',29,118);
```

Comment: I got another error: ERROR 1406 (22001): Data too long for column 'Type' at row 1. I have eight rows for the table and eight records inserted. I created an incorrect syntax for the INT datatype. For ex, Place_ID INT(6) will work with the total number of digits.

Comment: You can ask another question about that. Please put all necessary info in there with example data.

Answer (score 0):

incorrect quotes

```
INSERT INTO place 
VALUES (1000119,'Beijingshan',0,1032934,'740 Dragon Dr. 93402','PPL',29,118); <br>
```

Also, mentioning attribute names before inserting values is a good practice for tables having large number of attrib.

```
INSERT INTO table_name (column1,column2,column3,...) VALUES (value1,value2,value3,...);
```